# How do I reference parameters to other methods in XML documentation?

Tags: xml-documentation

My code contains a class with one method that returns an object that was originally passed as a parameter to another method.  I would like to indicate this relationship in the XML documentation mark-up.

```
class XmlDocThing
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Documentation for the other method.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="howDoIReferToThis">Magic object.</param>
    public void AnotherMethod(object howDoIReferToThis) { }

    /// <summary>
    /// Documentation for this method.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>The object passed as the <paramref name="howDoIReferToThis"/>
    /// argument of the <see cref="AnotherMethod"/> method.</returns>
    public object FromThisMethod() { return null; }
}
```

This results in the warning:

> Warning 1 XML comment on 'MyNamespace.XmlDocThing.FromThisMethod()'
>   has a paramref tag for 'howDoIReferToThis', but there is no parameter
>   by that name

The `<see cref="AnotherMethod"/>` element to do the method reference works as expected, but `<paramref>` doesn't appear to have a `cref` attribute (which only seems to apply to method and property members anyway), or any equivalent.

Is this even possible, and if so, how?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44000345/how-to-reference-a-parameter-of-a-different-method