# How to reference a parameter of a different method?

Tags: c#, sandcastle

Is it possible to reference a parameter from a different method than the one you are writing a summary for, and if so what is the syntax.

I know about `<paramref name="..."/>` but I don't know how to reference from a different method.

Simple humorous example in case I'm not making myself clear:

```
/// <summary>
/// Does magical Foo things!
/// </summary>
/// <param name="magic">Magic Toggle!</param>
public void Foo(bool magic)
{
    //...
}

/// <summary>
/// Does Bar things. More down to earth, no <paramref name="Foo(bool).magic"/> involved!
/// </summary>
public void Bar()
{
    //...
}
```

(Obviously the above is not a great use case, it's just for illustratory purposes.)

Comment: Same question as [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37433603/how-do-i-reference-parameters-to-other-methods-in-xml-documentation).

Comment: Feel like I should have found that... well anyway, almost exactly one year old and no answers. Perhaps it really isn't possible? :/

Comment: Method documentation has scope only for current method. There is no reason to add something explaining other method. That could change, being not available (e.g. `private`), and so on. Rather put that kind of additional notices into `<remark>` or, better, [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/programming-guide/xmldoc/see) other method.

Comment: "There is no reason" really is a strong statement. I have a pretty clear cut and simple use case for it, I just didn't include it because I wanted the question to be simple and succinct. PM me if you want to know the details.

Comment: (In short the remark section of method A wants to talk about a parameter of method B, because A is a special overload of B that had to be added to resolve a non-obvious generic overload-resolution result with jagged arrays with optional parameters to avoid breaking the principle of least surprise. Basically to avoid a pit of despair in some open-source library code. This issue is rather rare and I want to talk about it in the remarks.)

Answer (score 4):

There is no [recommended tag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/programming-guide/xmldoc/recommended-tags-for-documentation-comments) for this.

I suspect the reason why there is no recommended tag is because the primary use-case of this documentation is generated documentation in the style of the MSDN pages which doesn't make use of links to specific parameters of other methods. That said, its not a spec, just a recommendation. any valid XML you write will end up in the output XML file, so if you have a custom documentation generator which would make use of this there is nothing stopping you from adding "custom" tags that do whatever it is you need.

Personally I'd just do something like this:

```
interface IFoo
{
    void Foo(object otherParam);

    /// <summary>Documentation for this method.</summary>
    /// <returns>The object passed as the otherParam argument of
    /// the <see cref="Foo" /> method.</returns>
    object Bar();
}
```

Comment: Yeah it really is a minor issue. I just stumbled over the need to reference a parameter of another method and realized it might not be possible. The only _real_ reason I want to use xml-syntax to reference it is for refactoring to work in case the signature of the other method is ever changed for some reason. That is already quite unlikely in itself. But there was nothing wrong in asking right. Maybe in the future I find a stronger need for this, and then I'll be prepared - I thought.

Comment: *Just to clarify:* You are not explicitly stating that it's not possible to do what I want (without adding my own tags). Could you clarify this point? If you _know_ that it isn't possible please state so clearly and I will mark this as accepted. In the meantime have my +1 for a useful answer. :)

Comment: @AnorZaken I don't know for sure, no. I've only looked at the Microsoft recommended tags, but I've previously seen tags like `inheritdoc` that are fairly widely used, but not listed on that page.